# color row in a table using cellcolor

Tags: tables, color, cellcolor

I'm trying to color the title line of the table by using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

%% Packages %%
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz,float}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
%% Title Page %%

\addbibresource{refbib.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
{\tabulinesep=1.2mm    
    \begin{tabu} to 0.9\linewidth { |[2pt] *{3}{X[1 c]|}[2pt] } \tabucline[2pt]{-}
        \multicolumn{3}{ |[2pt]c|[2pt] }{\cellcolor{green!20}Initial Conditions} \\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
        $[x(0), y(0), z(0)]_{\text{R}}$ & [-29136.9, 0, 0] & m \\ \hline
        $[x(0), y(0), z(0)]_{\text{T}}$ & [0, 0, 0] & m \\ \hline    
        $[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{R}}$ & [680.7, 0, 680.7] & m/s \\ \hline
        $[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{Wind}}$ & [0, -10, 0] & m/s \\ \hline
        $[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{Wind Error}}$ & [0, 0, 0] & m/s \\ \hline
        Launch Angle & 45 & Deg \\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
    \end{tabu}}
\end{center}
\caption{Initial conditions for test 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, for some reason I still get this result:

[image]

Is there a reason that it doesn't show the line in green?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your preamble part, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`?

Comment: BTW, your code works fine, `Green` color comes for the first row...

Comment: For me, it doesn't work some why =S, added what you asked.

Comment: I've tried with your codes, still it works fine for me, can you confirm what `LaTeX` engine you are using, e.g., `PDFLaTeX` or `LaTeX` or `XELaTeX`?

Comment: Weird, im using PdfLatex in Texmaker.

Comment: That also works fine, may be the problem with the version, can you update the version and check...

Comment: I can confirm your findings. BTW, use of `tabu` package can be problematic, It is not maintained and contain bugs. Also not work well with `[table]{xcolor}` etc. I suggest you use `tabularx` instead of it.

Comment: @Zarko it doesn't work *because*  of the use of tabu. That is one of the open bug https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/issues/13.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I suspect this. Thank you for information (I rarely look on github).

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the `tabu` package for my tables. IUnfortunately this package with attractive intentions is buggy (especially after new version of array` package on which it is based) and not maintained.

For your table seems to be more appropriate to use ordinary `tabular` environment, not lock cells' content in "prison of horizontal and vertical tables' rules, left align cells' n. For more vertical space I would use of the `cellspace` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\usepackage{cellspace, makecell, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\caption{Initial conditions for test 1}
\label{my table}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{2}{>{$}Sl<{$}} l } 
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \rowcolor{mygreen!20}
\multicolumn{3}{Sc}{Initial Conditions}     \\ 
    \Xhline{0.75pt}
{[x(0), y(0), z(0)]_{\mathrm{R}}}   
        & [-29136.9, 0, 0]      & m         \\  
{[x(0), y(0), z(0)]_{\text{T}}}     
        & [0, 0, 0]             & m         \\
{[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{R}}}
    & [680.7, 0, 680.7]         & m/s       \\ 
{[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{Wind}}}
    & [0, -10, 0]               & m/s       \\ 
{[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{Wind Error}}}
    &  [0, 0, 0]                & m/s       \\ 
\text{Launch Angle}             
    & 45                        & Degrees   \\ 
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**The same table with use of the `siunitx` package. Use their names for units make their use more clear ... and hopefully encourage you to use it for all units in your document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\usepackage{cellspace, makecell, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\caption{Initial conditions for test 1}
\label{my table}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{2}{>{$}Cl<{$}} s } 
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \rowcolor{mygreen!20}
\multicolumn{3}{Cc}{Initial Conditions}             \\ 
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
{[x(0), y(0), z(0)]_{\mathrm{R}}}   
        & [-29136.9, 0, 0]      & \metre            \\  
{[x(0), y(0), z(0)]_{\text{T}}}     
        & [0, 0, 0]             & \metre            \\
{[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{R}}}
    & [680.7, 0, 680.7]         & \metre/\second    \\ 
{[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{Wind}}}
    & [0, -10, 0]               & \metre\per\second \\ 
{[V_{x}(0), V_{y}(0), V_{z}(0)]_{\text{Wind Error}}}
    &  [0, 0, 0]                & \metre\per\second \\ 
\text{Launch Angle}             
    & 45                        & Degrees   \\ 
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as it is at the first example.

Comment: Why not also add siunitx for the units in the last column?

Comment: @leandriis, good question!  OP use a lot of different packages but not `siunitx` (what one can expected, since table deals with units). The table background is unknown,  I miss column headers (what means values in each column), etc Anyway I will add a table version with use of `siunitx`, that OP will be aware for the `siunitx` package.